# Buttons come in different line

Tags: css, html

I have two buttons in html5,. I want that both should be displayed on same line, but they are coming in different line. what should i do. I have placed my code below :

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="stop"  style="width:50%;"/>

<input type="button" class="btn btn-reset" id="reset"  style="width:50%"/>
```

Comment: do these overlap? have you tried placing a newline in between?

Comment: It does not overlap. It worked well now. 
 
But I have one, more issue, Actually I have start stop timer. So when I click on start, stop and reset comes perfectly. But Now, when I click on stop, start and reset should also come in same line, which does not happen. If I set float as left in start also, then the whole design is distorted. what should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `width:49%` in both buttons.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/yq6a9/)

Comment: it worked. But I have one, more issue, Actually I have start stop timer. So when I click on start, stop and reset comes perfectly. But Now, when I click on stop, start and reset should also come in same line, which does not happen. If I set float as left in start also, then the whole design is distorted. what should i do ?

Answer (score 4):

Add `float:left;` in your input button

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/wWYgZ/2/

Comment: thanks, it worked.
But I have one, more issue, Actually I have start stop timer.
So when I click on start, stop and reset comes perfectly. But Now, when I click on stop, start and reset should also come in same line, which does not happen. If I set float as left in start also, then the whole design is  distorted. what should i do ?

Comment: thanks, it worked. But I have one, more issue, Actually I have start stop timer. So when I click on start, stop and reset comes perfectly. But Now, when I click on stop, start and reset should also come in same line, which does not happen. If I set float as left in start also, then the whole design is distorted. what should i do ?

Comment: @user2387900 can you create a fiddle for it so that i can look into it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yq6a9/

If you can have an idea..
I just click on start, and stop and reset appears. When i click on stop, start(restart) and reset appears. But here I want that when I click on stop, start should be in one line, if i keep float:left. But it does not happen. It distorts the page

Comment: @user2387900 what is wrong in this fiddle?? except you changed your width here

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33677/discussion-between-swapnesh-and-user2387900)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="stop"  style="width:50%; display:inline-block;"/>

<input type="button" class="btn btn-reset" id="reset"  style="width:50%; display:inline-block;"/>
```